How should αἱμάτων in John 1:13 be interpreted: “not of blood” or “not of bloods”?

John 1:13 NKJV says - who were born, not of blood, nor of the will of the
flesh, nor of the will of man, but of God.


The plural is curious. [1]
αἱμάτων
haimatōn

It's a Noun - Genitive Neuter Plural. However, NKJV, KJV, ESV and NASB all translate it in the singular.

King James Version - Which were born, not of blood, nor of the
will of the flesh, nor of the will of man, but of God.


English Standard Version - who were born, not of blood nor of the
will of the flesh nor of the will of man, but of God.


New American Standard Bible - who were born, not of [b]blood, nor of
the will of the flesh, nor of the will of a man, but of God.

NASB makes a footnote here that says: b. John 1:13 Lit bloods

Which is accurate in John 1:13: “not of blood” or “not of bloods”?
What does it mean to be born (plural) not of bloods?

Interesting, given Acts 17:26 And hath made of one blood all nations of men. Up-voted +1. The original [TR] is definitely plural in John 1:13.

Let us not separate John 1:13 from V12 which I will quote (my translation) -

However, as many as received Him, He have to them authority to be
children of God, to those trusting in His Name, who -

not of bloods
nor of the will of flesh
nor the will of (a) human

but of God were born.

The net effect of the three negative qualifications: not of blood, will of flesh nor human will, is to emphasize that the children of God were born spiritually of God.  The combination of flesh and blood(s) appears to allude to other instances in the NT indicating unaided human effort - see appendix below.
The plural "bloods" may mean that children of God are not born of ANY human of any of the many races (bloods) on earth - but only of God.
Jesus takes up this theme with Nicodemus (John 3) whom Jesus told:


V3: “Truly, truly, I tell you, no one can see the kingdom of God unless he is born from above."
V5&6: “Truly, truly, I tell you, no one can enter the kingdom of God unless he is born of water and the Spirit. Flesh is born of flesh,
but spirit is born of the Spirit.


APPENDIX - "Flesh and Blood"

Num 19:5 - And the heifer shall be burned in his sight. Its skin, its flesh, and its blood, with its dung, shall be burned.
Matt 16:17 - And Jesus answered him, “Blessed are you, Simon Bar-Jonah! For flesh and blood has not revealed this to you, but my Father who is in heaven.
1 Cor 15:50 - I tell you this, brothers: flesh and blood cannot inherit the kingdom of God, nor does the perishable inherit the imperishable.
Gal 1:16 - to reveal His Son in me so that I might preach Him among the Gentiles, I did not rush to consult with flesh and blood,
Eph 6:12 - For we do not wrestle against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the cosmic powers over this present darkness, against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly places.
Heb 2:14 - Since therefore the children share in flesh and blood, he himself likewise partook of the same things, that through death he might destroy the one who has the power of death, that is, the devil

In all these cases, mortal humans are implied - humans without any aid of divine instruction or enlightenment as they all appear to indirectly allude to the sacrifice in Num 19:5 where "flesh and blood" is idiom for a mortal/human person and all appear to indirectly allude to Num 19:5 (a dead animal)

Thank you for the answer. The thought is interesting. Though, I'm curious if "haima" is ever used to indicate races for (bloods).

@Jason_ - in the 98 occurrences in the NT John 1:13 is the ONLY plural instance - all others are singular

Oh, that's really interesting. I had just noticed that it was translated singular not the fact that among the whole corpus it was the ONLY plural. +1.

οἳ οὐκ ἐξ αἱμάτων οὐδὲ ἐκ θελήματος σαρκὸς ⸋οὐδὲ ἐκ θελήματος ἀνδρὸς⸌* ἀλλʼ ἐκ θεοῦ ἐγεννήθησαν. (John 1:13, NA28)
This verse is contrasting spiritual birth with physical birth, a topic which John brings up again in chapter 3.  αἱμάτων is plural because one genetically inherits two blood lines, one from the father and one from the mother. For the Jews the covenant with God was through physical inheritance.

Which were born (οἱ ἐγεννηθησαν [hoi egennēthēsan]). First aorist passive indicative of γενναω [gennaō], to beget, “who were begotten.” By spiritual generation (of God, ἐκ θεου [ek theou]), not by physical (ἐξ αἱματων [ex haimatōn], plural as common in classics and O. T., though why it is not clear unless blood of both father and mother; ἐκ θεληματος σαρκος [ek thelēmatos sarkos], from sexual desire; ἐκ θεληματος ἀνδρος [ek thelēmatos andros], from the will of the male).
--
Robertson, A. T. (1933). Word Pictures in the New Testament (John 1:13). Broadman Press.


+1. This makes sense that the physical aspect of human birth involves the bloodlines of both parents.

Before the death and resurrection of Jesus, every person could be placed in one of three groups, Gentile, Jew, or Levite. Biological ancestry was the determining factor.
By God's initiative, the Jews were separated from Gentiles and Levites from Jews. By God's initiative, anyone, regardless of their biological ancestry, could be born again as children of God.
Thus, those born of bloods could become children of God. Likewise, those born of flesh or of the will of man could become children of God.
Since there are three mentioned, bloods, flesh, or will of man, these describe Levites, Jews, and Gentiles.
Bloods reflects how Levites became a separate group among Jews.
Exodus 32 (ESV)

25 And when Moses saw that the people had broken loose (for Aaron had let them break loose, to the derision of their enemies), 26 then Moses stood in the gate of the camp and said, “Who is on the LORD's side? Come to me.” And all the sons of Levi gathered around him. 27 And he said to them, “Thus says the LORD God of Israel, ‘Put your sword on your side each of you, and go to and fro from gate to gate throughout the camp, and each of you kill his brother and his companion and his neighbor.’” 28 And the sons of Levi did according to the word of Moses. And that day about three thousand men of the people fell. 29 And Moses said, “Today you have been ordained for the service of the LORD, each one at the cost of his son and of his brother, so that he might bestow a blessing upon you this day.”

One can also see how the Levites position of offering the sacrifices agrees with bloods. Flesh refers to Jews, and will of man refers to Gentiles.
